# In Kubernetes how can I have a hard minimum number of pods for Deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

On my deployment I can set `replicas: 3` but then it only spins up one pod. Its my understanding that kubernetes will then fire up more pods as needed, up to three.

But for the sake of uptime I want to be able to have a *minimum* of three pods at all times and for it to maybe create more as needed but to never scale down lower than 3.

Is this possible with a Deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly as you did, you define 3 replicas in your `Deployment`.
Have you verified that you have enough resources for your Deployments?

#### Replicas example:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3 # <------- The number of your desired replicas
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

K8S will spin up a new pod if it **can do it** meaning, if you have enough resources, the resources are valid (like nodes, selectors, image, volumes, configuration, and more)

If you have defined 3 replicas and you still getting only 1, examine your deployment or your events.

#### How to view events

```sh
# To view all the events (don't specify pod name or namespace)
kubectl get events

# Get event for specific pod
kubectl describe event <pod name> --namespace <namespace>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you you're right. This was my understanding but what I was seeing happening was making me question my sanity. So hearing this confirmation made me go and check more deeply and it turns out there was a HorizontalPodAutoScaler in the namespace I didn't know about and it is of course causing the pods to horizontally auto scale. A bit of a derp on my part but thank you!